# Is is possible to turn off the computer fan+ the processor fan with programming?

Tags: c, windows, assembly

I am trying to observe if software can damage hardware today or not.For that I choose that choosing to shut  the computer fans would be a nice idea(else I would have preferred crashing the harddisk).I need to know the following:

1. Is it possible to do that anyone's computer?
2. Can this be dangerous to the hardware?
3. Choosing C is a good choice or should I go for Assembly language?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: whose fan are you trying to turn off?

Comment: What operating system ? Any possible answer will be OS-specific.

Comment: you _don't_ want to do that.

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish, and *on what OS*? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, programming in C can turn any computer fan off.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: You *may* want to do that, if your program is also monitoring the temperatures (e.g. "if the temperature is under 30 degrees Celsius, no point in running a fan"); ACPI should be doing that for you however...

Comment: Someone already does that, SpeedFan: http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: I am interested to do it with the help of programming

Comment: @Piskvor the *processor* fan?

Comment: @AakashM: Possibly, depends on the model. Some processors are even fanless (le gasp!). Of course, you probably don't want to *ever* switch the fans off for a 56 THz 2913-core server-grade CPU, but for something like a 1 GHz processor on a nanoITX, you may have situations where the processor only requires active cooling under heavy load. Again, this will be low-level mucking about in the BIOS, but some models may have the option.

Comment: @Piskvor fair enough. I have hard-to-shift memories of a 400MHz AMD processor I once had that died approx 2 seconds after its fan fell off :(

Comment: @AakashM:Didnt it shutdown because of overheating?

Comment: @fahad it seems there wasn't time for the OS or the BIOS to do anything, the chip itself went. This was a while ago mind, when (as I found out) this was 'just one of those things' with certain CPUs.

Comment: @AakashM:If you can help me determine the range of systems which had this problem,I would certainly be playing with there fans..

Comment: You can easily turn off the processor fan turning off the computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the fans spin for a reason: complex electronics overheat rather quickly. It would be easier to look into a specialized tool that does this, such as SpeedFan for Windows.

On the other hand, if you *really* want to do it, there are ways - however, they are mostly vendor- and product-specific. For Acer laptops on Linux, see e.g. [this](http://www.electronpusher.org/~rachel/acerfand) - note that it's very low-level (involves BIOS calls) and if it breaks, you get to keep both parts.

Answer (score 3):

The processor fan is usually controlled by hardware and cannot be controlled from software.

Some specialized fans may provide an API to do this, but it would be specific to that hardware only.

Answer (score 2):

If you do so, you will likely trigger thermal alarms in a short time and the pc will shut down in a few instants. Still, there is the danger of irreversibly damaging the hardware.

Comment: danger to hardware is interesting,this is what I am thinking that is there any way that software can cause danger to hardware.

Comment: @fahad: IIRC, there was a computer virus in the early 90s that tried to kill your hard drive by repeatedly spinning it up and down. Although these are normal activities, it did manage to break drives when executed for a prolonged period.

Comment: @Piskvor: And weren't there some who would repeatedly make the head bounce into it's stopping position with maximal speed? Or is this an urban myth?

Comment: @sbi: I cannot prove or disprove that, as I haven't actually seen the virus you describe, although I've *heard* of it.